# finding the $\lim_{x \rightarrow -2 }\frac{x+2}{x^3+8}$

Tags: limits

How do you solve $\lim_{x \rightarrow -2} \frac{x+2}{x^3+8}$ to get 1/12? I tried factoring out the denominator into $(x+2)(x+2)(x+2)$ and cancelling it out with the top but when you plug in 0 for x the denominator is still 0.

Comment: the bottom factors as $(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)$.

Comment: Generally, $a^n+b^n\neq(a+b)^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps
$$ \lim_{x\to -2} \frac{x+2}{x^3+8}=\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{x+2}{(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)} $$
$$ =\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{1}{x^2-2x+4}= \frac{1}{(-2)^2-2(-2)+4}=\frac{1}{4+4+4}=\frac{1}{12} $$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Notice that your factorisation is wrong.

$$x^3+8=(x+2)(x^2 −2x+4)$$

So, when $x=-2$, $\quad x^2 −2x+4=12$.
(You should not be plugging $0$ for $x$.)

Comment: I meant -2 but I got it now

Comment: @Jessica That's great! If you are happy with the answer, could you accept it please? Thanks!